# Gzip encoding result

Tags: php

Hi i am using php file_get_contents method to get content. For getting high content it makes problem about bandwidth. I like to get gzip format data to get and decode to it later.

I collected a sample one but it show quite similar content length. here it is

```
<?php
function fetchUrl( $url, $gzip = false ) {
        $raw = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context = stream_context_create( array(
                'http' => array(
                        'method' => 'GET',
                        'header' => 'Accept-Encoding:' . ( $gzip ? 'gzip,deflate' : 'identity' ) . "\r\n",
                )
        ) ) );
        if ( $raw === false ) {
                return false;
        }
        return $gzip ? gzdecode( $raw ) : $raw;
}

$src1 = fetchUrl( 'http://www.google.com' ); 
$src2 = fetchUrl( 'http://www.google.com', true );

echo strlen($src1). "<br>";
echo strlen($src2);
?>
```

which results

```
52233
52232
```

if there a better solution please help me or redirect me any solution present this site.

NB: i searched but do not get exact one, if i may wrong then provide that link where i get proper solution.

TIA.

Comment: Function `fetchUrl` returns uncompressed content, right ? Then why do you expect comparing Y to Y to produce a difference ? If you want to see the difference - then do not call `gzdecode`

Comment: @IVOGELOV actually i want compressed content from server as it costs low KB,so i expect $src2 will give me far less value then $src1, `fetchUrl` return both uncompressed and compressed data as i expect.

Comment: Actually, `fetchUrl` always returns uncompressed data - that is why `strlen` gives the same value. Try with `return $gzip ? $raw : raw;` and you will see the difference!!!

Comment: ow thats it,it works inner way,so when i see document size,it remains same,actual data achieved size is differ. thank you @IVOGELOV